# How to change if condition

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I have created a shortcode functions to display the state name in the content. I have created one page specially to display the state names into the content.

I have this line on my page - **Why Providers from [state name shortcodes] choose our company?** I have added the shortcode functions and it is working fine. when visitor from any of the U.S states will entry my page it will show state name on shortcodes.

What i need is:

When they visit my original page, it need to show like this **Why Providers choose our company?**

I need any suggestion to not to display the text **"from"**

And I have some more functions to display state code & state plan. Below function I have need to use. This will show only the state name. I used JSON array to show the state details.

```
 add_shortcode('US_STATE_NAME_WITH_TEXT',
 'mp_usstate_name_with_text');

 function mp_usstate_name_with_text() {

        $usstate_name = "";
        $chosen_state = [];
        global $STATES_ARRAY;
        //$states = json_encode(STATES_ARRAY);
        //alert("Value of States Array" + $STATES_ARRAY);
        //$state = $states.find(state => state.slugCode === get_query_var("usstate"));
        $state = array_filter($STATES_ARRAY, function($state) {
            return $state["slugCode"] === get_query_var("usstate");
        });

       if(count($state) > 0){
        $chosen_state = array_pop($state);
        if(!empty($chosen_state) ){ 
            $usstate_name = $chosen_state["name"]; 
        }
      }
        return .$usstate_name;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add "from" to return value of shortcode function.

```
return 'from ' . $usstate_name;
```

From

```
Why Providers from [state name shortcodes] choose our company?
```

to

```
Why Providers [state name shortcodes] choose our company?
```